# How to make dynamic fields from user input in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, dynamic, laravel-5.1

i'm having a lost here when i want to make dynamic fields based on user input. for example this is the field to receive user input to create a blank field:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'home')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('n', 'Parameter') !!}
        {!! Form::number('n', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'How Many Parameter to create ?']) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

after submitting. there should be a blank fields as many as the input above.
i've searched some reference, but there isn't much further information about the code that i can get. and i'm in a dilema. i'm hoping for a help. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Add method in your controller as:

```
public function anyMethodNameThatYouWant(Request $request)
{
    $number = request->input('n');
    return view('any-view-name-that-you-want',['number' => $number]);
}
```

Just submit the form to this method of your controller and you will get the number which had been posted by the user for creating fields.

In view file put the below code:
**any-view-name-that-you-want.balde.php**

```
@for ($index = 1; $index <= $number; $index++)
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="n{{ $index }}">Parameter{{ $index }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="n{{ $index }}" id="n{{ $index }}" value="" placeholder="Parameter{{ $index }}"  />
    </div>
@endfor
```

Now this will create the input fields for you.

You can post your form via ajax to get the number of inputs.When you are posting the form via ajax just change the return statement of controller method as below:

```
return view('any-view-name-that-you-want',['number' => $number])->__toString();
```

So it will give you the entire view in string format and you can easily send back this HTML response to your ajax request.
Hope this will help you.